# Trying to understand an RCSI example-The Potential Dangers of the Read Committed Snapshot Isolation Level

Tags: sql-server, transaction, isolation-level, snapshot-isolation

There's this article [The Potential Dangers of the Read Committed Snapshot Isolation Level](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2009/08/27/the-potential-dangers-of-the-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-level) which demonstrates RC vs RCSI isolation levels.

I get the RC example but not the RCSI one.In particular how the query has gotten the result **-3**.
Can somone explain how this query works under RCSI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under locking read committed it's very likely (but not guaranteed) that when two sessions run this code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @QtyRequired int, @QtyRemain int
SELECT @QtyRequired = 4
SELECT @QtyRemain = SUM(QTY) FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
IF @QtyRemain - @QtyRequired >= 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Inventory SET Qty = Qty - @QtyRequired
    WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
    -- Do other stuff in other tables or databases to check out the item
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    SELECT 'Checkout complete'
END
ELSE
    SELECT 'Not enough qty!'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

There will be enough difference in time that the second session runs

```
SELECT @QtyRemain = SUM(QTY) FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
```

after the first session has run

```
UPDATE Inventory SET Qty = Qty - @QtyRequired
WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
```

And so the second session will be unable to acquire an S lock on the row, and will be blocked until the first session commits.  This isn't a guarantee, however, as it's quite possible that both sessions run

```
SELECT @QtyRemain = SUM(QTY) FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
```

before either of them runs the update.

With RCSI it's simply more likely that they will both read the same value for @QtyRemain as the SELECT is never blocked by the pending UPDATE on the other session, and just returns the "last-known-good" value for the row from the version store.

But since the locking read committed version has the same problem, albeit in a smaller window, they are both broken, and should be fixed by changing the first query to:

```
SELECT @QtyRemain = SUM(QTY) FROM Inventory with (UPDLOCK) WHERE ItemID = 796 AND LocationID = 1
```

Which guarantees that even if two sessions attempt the query at the same time, one will be granted the U lock, and the other will be blocked until the first session commits.

Comment: Thanks very much for replying.In particular how did the RCSI query got a Qty of 3?Is it a random number,or can it be calculated precisely due to the way the two transactions interfere? I mean T1 reads Qtyremain=5 and then tries the update 5-4=1.Then T2 reads under RCSI the same sum Qtyremain 5 thus the update should be again 5-4=1 but when T2 tries to actually update, it blocks since T1 is already trying to update.After T1 commits, the Qty will now be 1.Then T2 will try to do Qty=Qty-QtyRemain that is Qty=1-4.Where is my flaw?

Comment: @microwth The flaw is that the new updated value is already calculated before the block. RC does not detect this. RCSI does but you don't get a block, you get an update conflict Error 3960

Comment: @Charlieface You don't get update conflicts in RCSI, since RCSI doesn't guarantee repeatable reads in the first place. In here, for instance, Brent mentions this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Comment: @microwth: Where is the value 3 mentioned? I didn't see that number in the article, nor in David's answer? I see the value -3, however (which is an expected number). Perhaps you misread -3 as 3?

Comment: @tibor- yes you are right.it is -3 ,I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Trying to explain how we end up with -3 in the table: Let's call the transactions A and B. A starts first:

```
Begin tran
Reads the value 5, store it in @QtyRemain and verify that we have >= 0 after subtraction of @QtyRequired (being 4)
Update, value in table after update is 1 (current val 5 minus required 4 = 1).
Waits...
End tran
```

And here's B, starts during the wait for tran A:

```
Begin tran
Reads the value 5, store it in @QtyRemain and verify we have >= 0 after subtraction of @QtyRequired (being 4)
Update, blocked until end of tran A...
...Update now occurs. Value in table after update is -3 (current val 1 minus required 4 = -3)
```